# Making Quick Look Helper less annoying

Tags: macos

On my system, the Quick Look Helper daemon regularly starts eating all available CPU cycles as it tries to create previews of 'new' files. This usually happens when I have a Finder window open to a directory I haven't looked at in a while, and this directory contains complex files (CAD files, video etc.)
A search of various Apple forums shows the problem is fairly common, but hasn't turned up a solution.
As far as I can tell, Quick Look Helper chokes on these files and goes into an infinite loop, consuming all available CPU and forcing the fans to maximum revs. The remedy is to kill the Quick Look Helper process twice in a row (after the first kill, it comes back up immediately and chokes again).

I've been doing this manually using Activity Monitor, but I'd like a more automated way. It should be possible to create a Unix script to kill the process, but this is a bit beyond my abilities.

- the process would have to kill Quick Look Helper by name (it gets a different PID every time). I can do this using [pkill](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030620102036392).
- the process should watch Quick Look Helper, and kill it if CPU usage climbs above 100% for more than a few seconds. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on Ask Different (apple.SE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely caused by a buggy Quick Look generator -- a plug-in that generates previews of additional file types. You can see what nonstandard QL generators are installed on your computer by looking in /Library/QuickLook. It's also possible there are some installed just in your user account; you can find these in the Finder by holding the Option key as you pull down the Go menu, then choosing Library from that menu (note: Library only appears while the Option key is held down!). Inside that Library folder, look for a QuickLook subfolder where your personal QL generators are stored.

If I'm right that it's a buggy QL generator, you can disable it by removing it from the QuickLook folder (remember which one it came from, in case you need to put it back!), and then I think logging out & back in.

You mentioned it freezing on directories full of CAD files, so I'd suspect a generator for those first (or any other file types that're frequently nearby when it freezes).

Comment: I've removed two plugins (Office and Meshkit) from /System/Library/Quicklook. That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Office and Meshkit weren't the culprit, it seems. I use my CAD program to generate STL files for 3D printing, and some of these are seen as text files by my system. Not entirely without logic, I've opened STL-ASCII files in a text editor (to concatenate two files). I've removed the Text QL generator file from /System/Library/Quicklook.

Comment: The symptoms are also caused by corruption in the file QL is working on. If QuickLook can't make sense of a file, it will hang until the offending file is removed (or QL is force-quit).